# Trying to set timezone to EST in Django

Tags: django

I want to set my django app to work with all times in EST.
I seem to be missing something about how to set this up?

```
>>>from django.conf import settings
>>>print settings.USE_TZ
True
>>>print settings.TIME_ZONE
EST
>>>from django.utils import timezone
>>>timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 22, 16, 40, 50, 893000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the local time you need to use localtime setting else it will always return UTC

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

Comment: so here localtime time means the timezone I specified in settings?

Comment: Yes. Also the time that gets sent to your db.